How to use reverseProxy with Http4k?
Can we use Http4k as a reverse proxy server? I see that Http4k has reverseProxy function, but couldn't find any example usage. How do I forward requests? I tried following and it works, but is there any better way?
 reverseProxy("" to {  req->
    OkHttp()(req.uri(req.uri.host(config.hostname).port(config.port).scheme(config.scheme)))
})


This example also uses reverseProxy. Does it help?

Thanks. It helped a bit. I tried with explicit OkHttp call, (question updated) but is there any better way?

Can you elaborate what's wrong with this way? What exactly are you looking for when this already does what you want?

I was expecting http4k to take care of Http call, instead we explicitly using OkHttp

Turns out, there is no alternative way to implement this behaviour. We need instance of Http client explicitly. Some minor refactoring using extend so that we don't have to copy all attributes.
val client = OkHttp()
...
reverseProxy("" to { req ->
      client(req.uri(config.upstreamUri().extend(req.uri)))
}) 

